# Is it possible to import UV-maps in Unity3D without manually importing the associated texture?

Tags: unity, textures

When i import an object from Maya with a defined UV-map i have to manually import the texture (image) and assign it to the material.

Is there a way to keep the materials texture reference from Maya when importing into Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the textures its looking for are in a folder called /Textures/ somewhere in the asset view, and named the same as whatever you're calling it in Maya, it'll "just work".

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-Mesh.html

Comment: When i set my project preferences in Maya to use /Textures in the Asset folder and placed the texture files there, they showed up in unity when i saved the scene directly in /Assets and instantiated the prefabs.